# How to delete all after last slash?

Tags: notepad++

How to delete all after last /.
I have a file with urls.

```
http://www.enworld.org/forum/member.php?1-Morrus&language=uk
http://weld.in.ua/forum/member.php/1-%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD?langid=5
```

Need a solution for notepad++

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Open your file in `Notepad++`.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
- To the `Find what` textbox, add Regular expression :`[^/]+$`
- Keep the `Replace with` textbox empty(In screenshot that is my mouse cursor).
- **Be sure to check `Regular Expression` radio button at the bottom**
- Your Notepad++ dialog should look as below:

[image]

- Click `Replace All` button.
- You are done..!! Your final output will be as below:

  http://www.enworld.org/forum/

  http://weld.in.ua/forum/member.php/

**Note :**

Regular Expression `[^/]+$` matches at least one of (anything not a slash) followed by end of the string:

Comment: On lines that look like "Disallow: /component/content/article/8-slideshow/" nothing happen. Should be removed everything after "Disallow: /component/" (after last slash) but does not work. Strange.