# How to delete everything after second slash

Tags: regex, notepad++

On this topic:
[How to delete all after last slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758641/how-to-delete-all-after-last-slash) is an answer marked as accepted but that answer do not cover the situation when you have another slash at the end.

**I** want to delete everything after second slash (/)

**Example:**

```
Redirect 410 /component/content/
Redirect 410 /rm/land/8919/
Redirect 410 /a5-Q_/MART_Horizon_Afdj/
```

**to become**

```
Redirect 410 /component/
Redirect 410 /rm/
Redirect 410 /a5-Q_/
```

Comment: Do you need a code in some language or Find-Replace feature of editor to complete the task using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an expression `^([^/]*/[^/]*/).*$`, and replace with `$1`

[image]

`([^/]*/[^/]*/)` expression captures the part that you want to keep; `.*$` captures the rest of the string to the end of line. Replacing with `$1` removes the unwanted portion of the string.

Comment: Thanks! I do not understand who downvote everything on this topic? Is Christmas gift from Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yeah I don't understand the downvote either. I upvoted though, because this answers the question.

Comment: @mariusfv There's a good deal of people who vote based on their opinion of whether or not a question or answer deserves to be on the site. For example, I got downvoted on a different question today, because the voter thought that the author of the question did not put in enough effort into solving the problem, even through OP outlined a solution that he wanted to improve upon. I ignore these downvotes, though, because they don't offer anything of value to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, how you could achieve deleting the part of String that you ask for with the use of regex. I created a simple array containing source String to make the code look more clear:

```
String[] strings = { "Redirect 410 /component/content/", "Redirect 410 /rm/land/8919/", "Redirect 410 /a5-Q_/MART_Horizon_Afdj/" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Redirect 410 /[^/]*/).*"); // Here is the regex I used to get needed part of String
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(strings[i]);
    if(m.find()) {
        strings[i] = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Output you get when using this code:

```
Redirect 410 /component/
Redirect 410 /rm/
Redirect 410 /a5-Q_/
```

This is a solution according to Java language as you didn't specify what language you were working with, but I think that solution in other languages could be similar to this one.

Comment: I edited and improved my answer, I hope you reconsider the downvote as the code works better now.

Comment: Someone just downvoted the question and all the answers. I don't think it was directed at you specifically.

Comment: @JacobH Thank you for pointing it. I haven't thought about it that way, because I haven't noticed that kind of behavior here yet - you may be right actually.